# Populate ListView with Runnable - Returns Too Many

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I'm putting together an app which has a listview in a relativeLayout with a couple LinearLayouts inside of it. So I have my adapter, and a function to get the items into the list. This function is only called in the OnCreate function of the apps main process and is called in a runnable on a thread. Can you all see any reason why this thing might be calling adding into my array so many times? (the for loop gets called thousands of times when I've only added one thing to the array.
In the OnCreate method for the main process:

```
      array = new ArrayList<Item>(); //The misbehaving array
      ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ItemList);
      this.m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.Itemlist_item, array);
      lv.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
      viewItems = new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
             getItems();
          }
      };
      Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewItems, "ListThread");
      thread.start();
```

The getItems function and the second Runnable:

```
private void getItems(){
  try{
     //Try Some Stuff
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
  }
  runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
  @Override 
  public void run() {
    if(array != null && array.size() > 0){
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //This loop is where I'm seeing the problem
        for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++) {
            listAdapter.add(array.get(i));
        }
    }
  }
};
```

And the list adapter:

```
  public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

        public ArrayList<Item> items;
        public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View conView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = conView; //The content view

            if (v == null){
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlist_item, null);
            }

            Item o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null){
                TextView name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                if(name != null){
                    name.setText("name:"+o.getItemName());
                }
            }

            return v;

        }

    }
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated.
Thanks,
-Chris

Comment: have you logged array.size() to see how big it thinks it is?

Comment: Yes, it just runs over and over until it has tens of thousands of entries

Comment: how many elements are in the 'array' object? i.e. how many times do you think that the loop should go?

Comment: only once right now. but in the future it will go as many times as an object is created by the user

Comment: Add this line right before the for loop Log.i("TAG" "" + array.size()); Run it again and check the log to see what it outputs.

Comment: It logs 1. I just don't know what's going on in that loop to increase its size.

Comment: @user1425245 Ok move the log statement to inside the for loop and see how many times it prints to the log.

Comment: Yeah I did that, that's how I know its returning tens of thousands of times. the log gets called that many times as well.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code for listAdapter. Something must be happening in there that is making array object grow.

Comment: I just added every piece of code that deals with that variable

Comment: When and how does it change from 'items' to 'array'?

Comment: oh sorry, those are the same variable, I'm editing names for the code to make more sense, I'll fix that

Comment: Ok, When you put the log statement from my answer inside the for loop, does it print "1" every time to the log or does it increase like "1..2..3..4"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ListView` and other such UI widgets that work with an Adapter do not allow the contents of the adapter to change unexpectedly on them. You need to tell the `ListView` about the change you make before it next tries to interact with your adapter. If you allow another thread to modify the adapter, or modify it on the main thread but don't tell `ListView` about the change before allowing anything else to happen, you will randomly (due to races) get exceptions thrown by `ListView` about the adapter changing unexpectedly.

Instead, something like this should work (from HackBod's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244952/844882)):

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Item> {
    private ArrayList<Item> mItems;

    public int getCount() {
        return mItems != null ? mItems.size() : 0;
    }

    public MyItem getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(i);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

and then populate the `ListView` with,

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private void setDataFromThread(ArrayList<Item> data) {
    // Enqueue work on mHandler to change the data on
    // the main thread.
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mItems = newData;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i read the link and you will want to extend BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: the OP might even be able to get away with putting `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `for` loop itself...? Not 100% sure though from the code he/she has provided... I think allowing the `Adapter` itself to populate its own data (rather than adding the items sequentially on a separate thread) makes much more sense though.

Comment: AlexLockwood: I have put notifyDataSetChanged() in the loop before but saw no change in the behavior of the application. I've also tried just before and just after the loop just to try everything and still saw no change. I will definitely play around with some of that code, that might be what's going on. Why would it grow the array itself though?
I'm not totally sure what you're saying to change in the comment, but I'll definitely work to see if I can try that.

@L7ColWinters I haven't done much with adapters, why would BaseAdapter be better?

Comment: @user1425245 do you ever remove items from the arraylist? because the reason why the loop is executed thousands of times is probably because `array.size()` has grown into a huge number.

Comment: no, but there's no reason it should add anything more than once. the way I have it set up it should just be a list of the items. Going into the loop the size is 1, after that it grows, but my question is why?

Comment: @user1425245 I don't know for sure, but I think Since you've passed array to the Adapter constructor I think each time you add something to the Adapter it also gets added to the array.