# error notifyDataSetChanged in BroadcastReceiver in AsyncTask when application is closed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, notifydatasetchanged

My application got an error when my app is closed and new data is received in `BroadcastReceiver` class in `AsyncTask` when it wants to use `notifyDataSetChanged` method for my viewpager.
please help me!

Here is my code  :

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> p1 = new PostService1(context, url,
        object, new ServiceCallback() {

            public void onTaskComplete(String response) {

                if (!response.equals("")) {

                    commentList = gson.fromJson(response,
                            new TypeToken<List<Comment>>() {
                            }.getType());

                    if (commentList.size() != sizeOfCommentList) {
                        DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(
                                context, "DB", null);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
                        DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
                        CommentDao commentDao = daoSession.getCommentDao();

                        for (int i = sizeOfCommentList; i < commentList
                                .size(); i++) {
                            commentList.get(i).setIsFavorite(false);
                            commentDao.insert(commentList.get(i));
                        }

                        final DBHandling dbHandling = new DBHandling();
                        dbHandling.fillCommentList(this, context);

                        MainActivity.viewPager2.getAdapter()
                                .notifyDataSetChanged();

                        db.close();
                        helper.close();
                    }
                } else
                    System.out.println("NO New Data Recived....!!!");
            }

        }).execute();
```

Comment: Do you get a NullPointerException? Then first check if one of these == null (MainActivity, viewPager2, viewPager2.getAdapter()) before calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: non of them is null, the error is: illegalStateException on *notifyDataSetChanged*

Comment: then update the logcat and also indicate the line where exactly you are getting the error?

Comment: if you are using an ArrayAdapter check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244330/is-arrayadapter-thread-safe-in-android-if-not-what-can-i-do-to-make-it-thread/6244952#6244952