# How can I make my list thread safe in order to use it with a custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

In my app, I am backing a ListView with a LinkedList. I am using an custom ArrayAdapter in order to fill the list:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

    Context context;
    int resource;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Message> messages) {
        super(context, resource, messages);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MessageHolder messageHolder = null;

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            messageHolder = new MessageHolder();
            messageHolder.chat_information = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_information);
            messageHolder.chat_message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);

            row.setTag(messageHolder);
        } else {
            messageHolder = (MessageHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Message message = getItem(position);
        messageHolder.chat_information.setText(message.getSenderName() + Constants.NEWLINE + message.getSendTime());
        messageHolder.chat_message.setText(message.getMessageText());

        return row;
    }

    private class MessageHolder {
        TextView chat_information;
        TextView chat_message;
    }
}
```

I realized, however, that LinkedList is not thread safe. I would like to use [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [LinkedBlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html), but they only return arrays, and the adapter requires a List.

Is there any way to adapt this custom ArrayAdapter to use one of these thread safe methods or will I need to iterate over the array of objects in order to fill a List to use?

Comment: This may be not exactly a duplicate but it won't hurt to take a look at this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6244952/5015207)

Comment: You should only modify the adapter data from the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting the list to use the internal SQLite database instead, and used a SimpleCursorAdapter to back up the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Collections class can be used to wrap a List, making it synchronized (i.e. thread safe). For example:

```
LinkedList<String> notThreadSafeList = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> threadSafeList = Collections.synchronizedList(notThreadSafeList);
```

See also:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)